# notification is displaying in other apps also

Tags: android

I am using the following code to check the internet connection in my entire app.

```
public class UpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetInfo = connectivityManager
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        boolean isConnected = activeNetInfo != null
                && activeNetInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
        if (isConnected){
            Log.i("NET", "connecte" + isConnected);
        Toast.makeText(context, "net Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        .show();
        }
        else{
            Log.i("NET", "not connecte" + isConnected);
        Toast.makeText(context, "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when their is no internet connection/wi-fi signal, the toast message is displaying in other apps too.. how do I avoid that?

Thanks:)

Comment: You should use context of your application instead of using context, that you get through params

Comment: @Nickolai thanks but i am new to this. can you please explain me how can I do that?

Comment: Please, check my anser. Hope it helps you resolve your issue.

Comment: Assuming that you are only want to get these event when you activity in running. To achieve this you need to register this broadcast reciever in your `Activity` `onStart()` mehtod and unregister the broadcast receiver when the user go out of your `Activity` (in `onPause()` method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an application class:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private static MyApplication instance;

    // Returns the application instance 
    public static MyApplication getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = this;
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Add to manifest:

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        ... >
```

In your broadcast receiver:

```
Toast.makeText(MyApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext(), "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this or getBaseContext() instead of contex .

Answer (score 0):

You are using BroadcastReceiver receiver to check whether there is an internet connection. This will get executed whenever there is a change in network connectivity irrespective of the application. Since you are new, I'll explain it.

We can relate Broadcast receiver to a radio which listens for certain type of broadcasts and Broadcast is something which is send by the android system when ever an event occurs. So if the event is of the type of your broadcast receiver, you will get it.

So from your application if you just need to check for connection, you can simply create a method and call it.

```
 public boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetInfo = connectivityManager
            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    boolean isConnected = activeNetInfo != null
            && activeNetInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    if (isConnected){
        Log.i("NET", "connecte" + isConnected);
    Toast.makeText(context, "net Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
    .show();
    }
    else{
        Log.i("NET", "not connecte" + isConnected);
    Toast.makeText(context, "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
    }

return isConnected;
}
```

Call this method, whenever you need to check the connection.

OR

if you need to get notified of the above event changes as you require above, you can use the same broadcast receiver and instead of registering the broadcast receiver in Manifest file, register it from code of your application when it starts and unregister it when your application ends.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to say none of the answers actually answers the original question "... the toast message is displaying in other apps too.. how do I avoid that?"

Toast is shown irrespective of which app is on the top. It is designed that way. So you can not 'avoid' that. You have to avoid using Tosat to avoid this behavior. The receiver acts in the background and shows a Toast. It does not bother which app is being shown currently to the user.

Please check this link also.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html